# Show/Hide GridViewColumns through ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, contextmenu, dependency-properties

I have a ListView with some GridViewColumns and I'd like to be able to show or hide them through checkable items in a ContextMenu.

*MainView.xaml:*

```xml
<ListView>
  <ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem x:Name="cma" Header="a" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True"/>
      <MenuItem x:Name="cmb" Header="b" IsCheckable="True"/>
      <MenuItem x:Name="cmc" Header="c" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True"/>
      <MenuItem x:Name="cmd" Header="d" IsCheckable="True"/>
    </ContextMenu>
  </ListView.ContextMenu>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <c:GridViewColumnExt c:GridViewColumnExt.IsVisible="{Binding ElementName=cma, Path=IsChecked}">
        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="a"/>
      </c:GridViewColumnExt>
      <c:GridViewColumnExt c:GridViewColumnExt.IsVisible="{Binding ElementName=cmb, Path=IsChecked}">
        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="b"/>
      </c:GridViewColumnExt>
      <c:GridViewColumnExt c:GridViewColumnExt.IsVisible="{Binding ElementName=cmc, Path=IsChecked}">
        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="c"/>
      </c:GridViewColumnExt>
      <c:GridViewColumnExt c:GridViewColumnExt.IsVisible="{Binding ElementName=cmd, Path=IsChecked}">
        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="d"/>
      </c:GridViewColumnExt>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

*GridViewColumnExt.cs:*

```
public class GridViewColumnExt : GridViewColumn
{
  private double _visibleWidth = double.NaN;

  public bool IsVisible
  {
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsVisibleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(GridViewColumnExt), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, OnIsVisibleChanged));

  private static void OnIsVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var newValue = bool.Parse(e.NewValue.ToString());
    var column = (GridViewColumnExt)d;
    var header = (GridViewColumnHeader)column.Header;
    header.IsEnabled = newValue;
    if (newValue)
    {
      column.Width = column._visibleWidth;
      header.IsEnabled = true;
      header.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
      column._visibleWidth = column.Width;
      column.Width = 0;
      header.IsEnabled = false;
      header.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
  }
}
```

<strike>MainViewModel.cs</strike> (Never mind, the solution doesn't need this)

The problem:

- When the window is first shown, columns a and c are visible
- When the ContextMenu is first shown, columns a and c become hidden and only column b is shown. Also, only column b is checked in the ContextMenu

Does anyone know what causes this?

**Solution:**

Removed binding to ViewModel properties and and just set the MenuItem.IsChecked to a default value.
By the way, if anyone has an even better way of handling this kind of stuff, please let me know :)

Comment: That code in `OnIsVisibleChanged` is horrible to read, spell out the proper names instead of one-letter variables.

Comment: I guess you're right, I just figured I wanted less text in my examples. Fixed it now, just for you :)

Comment: Less code is fine if you sketch something for yourself that's going to be thrown away later, please just do not do it when other people need to read it and are supposed to understand it / if there are issues with it (i.e. if you post it here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FallbackValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx) is for when a binding is unable to return a value.  Column b is checked and visible because you're setting it to true in the constructor.  Update your constructor appropriately.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
  public MainViewModel()
  {
    ColumnChecked_a = true;
    ColumnChecked_b = true;
    ColumnChecked_c = true;
  }
}
```

Also, I'm thinking the columns' visibility changes because the contextmenu maybe isn't "created" until the right-click.  Try a normal menu and see if that works, yeah.